# Characteristic equation for recurrence relations

Tags: recurrence-relations

This year we learned this method of characteristic equation to find the formula for the general element of a string of numbers (i.e. $a_n$)

> the characteriatic equation of the recurrence relation
>   $a_n=p_1a_{n-1}+...+p_ka_{n-k}$ is:
>   $t^k=p_1t^{k-1}+...+p_kt^0$.
>   My question is very vague: how is this method correct? I'm not saying I can't find the truth in it, I just can't understand how one can reach the descovery of this method. More accurately, what is the analogy behind it? Why is it used a polynomial in help for its solvation? I hope I made my point one way or another and that you could help me to find out the mistery behind it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The key remark is that, if $\lambda$ is a root of the characteristic polynomial, then $a_n=\lambda^n$ satisfies the recursion.  Just write it down!  (Note:  if the characteristic equation has multiple roots then the technique gets a little less clear).